# How to Call Calendar in my Application using Intents?

Tags: android

How to Call **Calendar** in my Application using Intents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an `Intent` that looks something like this:

```
Intent calendarIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);  
calendarIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
calendarIntent.putExtra("title", "Title");
calendarIntent.putExtra("beginTime", startTimeMillis);
calendarIntent.putExtra("endTime", endTimeMillis);
calendarIntent.putExtra("description", "Description");
```

You can then start it by calling this:

```
startActivity(calendarIntent);
```

Comment: And here are the available intents: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intents

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the calendar app or the form for adding a new event to the calendar?

Either way. Refer to this answer:

[how can i open the calendar from my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034788/how-can-i-open-the-calendar-from-my-app/5035119#5035119)