# Call calendar using intent

Tags: android

I use Samasung GalaxyTab 2.2 and i want to call calendar in my Application using Intents

I used

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
intent.setClassName("com.android.calendar", "com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity"); 
startActivity(intent);
```

and

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setType("text/calendar");
startActivity(i);
```

but it doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

As a general advice, I would recommend you to post the stacktrace of your errors to obtain better help.
About your issue, I think you are not doing it the right way, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034788/how-can-i-open-the-calendar-from-my-app).

You have to add a component on your intent :

```
Intent i = new Intent();

//Froyo or greater (mind you I just tested this on CM7 and the less than froyo one worked so it depends on the phone...)
cn = new ComponentName("com.google.android.calendar", "com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity");

//less than Froyo
cn = new ComponentName("com.android.calendar", "com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity");

i.setComponent(cn);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: the error that i got when i use your method  :

    02-03 11:20:21.433: E/AndroidRuntime(16693): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.google.android.calendar/com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?