# How to open Calendar app and restart current app in background simultaneously?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a situation in my current app where on tapping on a dialog fragment I have to restart the current app in background (or take to home activity) and open calendar app at the same time. I tried firing 2 intents at the same time but it didn't work. I also tried to use `AsyncTask's executeOnExecutor` but the order is not always guaranteed. Can someone please explain me how to handle situation like these?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034788/how-can-i-open-the-calendar-from-my-app

Comment: Thanks for the link @Anjali but opening Calendar isn't an issue for me but restarting the app (or taking to the home activity) in the background is

Comment: what flow exactly you want?? from your application you fire intent of calendar in that case your application is already running in your background.

Comment: Yes my app is already running in background when the Calendar is open but with Activity X visible. Now I want the app to go back to Home Activity from Activity X (in the background) while still having Calendar app opened for the user

Comment: You can go to the MainActivity when you return back to your app

Comment: @arol_123 absolutely. But how can we detect return to the app?

Comment: Ah! The `onPause()` and `onResume()` methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have write following code to launch activity first and calendar intent after that:

```
public void openCalendar(Context mCtx){

Intent activityIntent = new Intent(mCtx, HomeActivity.class);
startActivity(activityIntent );


Intent i = new Intent();

//Froyo or greater (mind you I just tested this on CM7 and the less than froyo one worked so it depends on the phone...)
cn = new ComponentName("com.google.android.calendar", "com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity");

//less than Froyo
cn = new ComponentName("com.android.calendar", "com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity");

i.setComponent(cn);
startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anjali, that worked! I misread when you first shared the link in the comments

Comment: this is not mention in the link:)